# Find nth occurrence of a symbol and replace using regular expression

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a file with more than 20K lines and in each line we have exactly 151 '@' symbols as a delimiter. I need to replace value between 104th, 105th and 105th and 106th occurrence of '@' symbol. I tried with Excel but having issues with date fields and felt replacing in Notepad++ is easy. Could anyone provide inputs on the regex? I tried with replacing with nth occurrence of the symbol but it didn't work.

**Sample Line**

> `9007;624;@0@0@1@Company & Co. "XYZ" ;Comp & Co. HG;@@@Ger;Ger;@@@@0@0@@@@@@@@@uid=XYZ@@@@@Gery;@0@@@@@0@@@@@@@T@@@@@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@1@1@1@1@1@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@08.007.001.001 Bs;08.007.001.004 Zahlungen;üüüüüüü;äääää;@Sct;2006;Mar;da das Haus;@@@$S0et7xV0@568;536871132;36108;536871497;536871712;536871449;536907021;148000;@THA@@@uid=Compa@03/03/2016;12:41:00:00@doc@096@@0@@1@@@OHG | 0624 | Ger | 9007 | Ger;@@2005;1953;@B48D3B01257184408AF2F2D69BAC1DEF000000000000@268471076@@@@@@@0@@@@@@07/24/2012;07:39:00:00@@@@@@@@@@@@$S0et7xV0@0@2147483935@19532.SDL`

Highlighted in bold needs to be replaced. Appreciate anyone's insights on this.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to replace it by?

Comment: Replace with a pre-defined text.

Comment: So two texts? You keep the @ separator between them? Can you edit your question and show what you have tried and what is holding you back in doing this?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the following replacement instruction (press <kbd>Ctrl+H</kbd> to open Find/Replace dialog):

**Find what:** `^((?:[^@]*@){104})[^@]*@[^@]*`
**Replace with:** `\1Hello@World`
**Search mode:**
⦿ Regular expression

<kbd>Replace All</kbd>

Here the two texts are replaced by "Hello" and "World". Adapt as needed.

Break down of the regex:

- `^` matches the start of a line
- `[^@]*@` matches a sequence of non-@ characters, followed by one @.
- `(?:   ){104}`: repeats 104 times the pattern enclosed within `(?: )`
- `(     )`: captures the matched text in a capture group that can be referenced with `\1`.

Comment: Thanks much for the answer. However, I tried with above regex but it did not work. As I said in my question, I will have line with @ as delimiter and need to replace the value in between 104th, 105th and 105th, 106th occurrence of @ with predefined text.

For ex: 

Actual Line -> A@B@C@D@E@F@G@H@I@@J (Consider @ before D is the 104th occurrence in a line for ex)
Expected Output -> A@B@C@TEST@STRING@F@G@H@I@@J (D & E are replaced with TEST and STRING)

Comment: I tested this with the input you gave in the question, and this worked for me. The "Actual Line" you give here does not have 105 @ characters, so it won't work with that. Your question didn't specify what the expected output is for the given example, so I had to use dummy text. Would be better to complete your question and provide the expected output literally. I just did the operation again, and it works as you describe in this comment.

Comment: Thanks for the note. I checked again and see that there are 151 occurrences of '@' symbol in the given input. Please note that value may or may not be there between delimiter.

Comment: Yes, all that is taken into account. Like I said it works for me: I pasted the example input in Notepad++ with several other lines of text, applied the Find/replace operation, and it replaced the text you marked in bold with "Hello" and "World". If it doesn't work for you then I cannot help you. It works for me (using Notepad++ v8.4.8)

Comment: See it run also on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/EstXhI/1)

Comment: Yes, even for me it worked in regex101. Strangely it doesn't work in my notepad++ v5.9.2. May be I need to upgrade and check once. Thanks much for your time and providing the solution.

Comment: The issue is with Notepad version. I tried in 6.9 and it works. Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm, version v5.9.2 is indeed an old relic. According to [this page](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/news/v623-end-of-world-edition/), version v6.2.3 dates from 2012, so you had a version that was more than a decade old!